# Branch cut rotation of the logarithm function?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

in my text book i have an exercise that uses a different way of expressing the logarithm:

$\log z = \ln  + iθ$, $\ z = e^{i\theta}$, $\ r>0$, $\ -\pi/2 < \theta < 3\pi/2 $

I wonder how the argument of the function was changed from the usual definition $\ -\pi < \theta < \pi $ ?

For more clarifications :[here is the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7zfP.jpg) (I apologize it's in italian, but i think it's quite clear).

Comment: you can change the branch cut when necessary. They need the negative real axis so they moved the branch cut to the negative imaginary axis. Otherwise the integration is much harder if there is a branch cut in the way.

Comment: But how do i change it? That's what i'm not really getting..

Comment: All they're doing is change $\arg(z)$. Values in the third quadrant, originally having principal arguments in the range $(-\pi, -\pi/2]$ and instead assigned values $(\pi, 3\pi/2]$ by adding $2\pi$ to the angle. Everything else remains the same.